# Hibernate create too much java classes

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I generate java classes from db with hibernate. In configuration i set to generate: 
[image]

And get 3 files from each table. For example:

Address.java

```
package gen;

// Generated 16.08.2012 12:47:01 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

/**
* Address generated by hbm2java
*/
public class Address implements java.io.Serializable
{

private AddressId id;

public Address()
{
}

public Address(AddressId id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public AddressId getId()
{
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(AddressId id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

}
```

AddressId.java

```
package gen;

// Generated 16.08.2012 12:47:01 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

/**
* AddressId generated by hbm2java
*/
public class AddressId implements java.io.Serializable
{

private String codeOkato;
private String codeKladr;
private String postalCode;
private String region;
private String house;
private String building;
private String structure;
private String apartment;
private String note;

public AddressId()
{
}

public AddressId(String codeOkato, String codeKladr, String postalCode, String region, String house, String building,
        String structure, String apartment, String note)
{
    this.codeOkato = codeOkato;
    this.codeKladr = codeKladr;
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
    this.region = region;
    this.house = house;
    this.building = building;
    this.structure = structure;
    this.apartment = apartment;
    this.note = note;
}

public String getCodeOkato()
{
    return this.codeOkato;
}

public void setCodeOkato(String codeOkato)
{
    this.codeOkato = codeOkato;
}

public String getCodeKladr()
{
    return this.codeKladr;
}

public void setCodeKladr(String codeKladr)
{
    this.codeKladr = codeKladr;
}

public String getPostalCode()
{
    return this.postalCode;
}

public void setPostalCode(String postalCode)
{
    this.postalCode = postalCode;
}

public String getRegion()
{
    return this.region;
}

public void setRegion(String region)
{
    this.region = region;
}

public String getHouse()
{
    return this.house;
}

public void setHouse(String house)
{
    this.house = house;
}

public String getBuilding()
{
    return this.building;
}

public void setBuilding(String building)
{
    this.building = building;
}

public String getStructure()
{
    return this.structure;
}

public void setStructure(String structure)
{
    this.structure = structure;
}

public String getApartment()
{
    return this.apartment;
}

public void setApartment(String apartment)
{
    this.apartment = apartment;
}

public String getNote()
{
    return this.note;
}

public void setNote(String note)
{
    this.note = note;
}

public boolean equals(Object other)
{
    if ((this == other))
        return true;
    if ((other == null))
        return false;
    if (!(other instanceof AddressId))
        return false;
    AddressId castOther = (AddressId) other;

    return ((this.getCodeOkato() == castOther.getCodeOkato()) || (this.getCodeOkato() != null
            && castOther.getCodeOkato() != null && this.getCodeOkato().equals(castOther.getCodeOkato())))
            && ((this.getCodeKladr() == castOther.getCodeKladr()) || (this.getCodeKladr() != null
                    && castOther.getCodeKladr() != null && this.getCodeKladr().equals(castOther.getCodeKladr())))
            && ((this.getPostalCode() == castOther.getPostalCode()) || (this.getPostalCode() != null
                    && castOther.getPostalCode() != null && this.getPostalCode().equals(castOther.getPostalCode())))
            && ((this.getRegion() == castOther.getRegion()) || (this.getRegion() != null && castOther.getRegion() != null && this
                    .getRegion().equals(castOther.getRegion())))
            && ((this.getHouse() == castOther.getHouse()) || (this.getHouse() != null && castOther.getHouse() != null && this
                    .getHouse().equals(castOther.getHouse())))
            && ((this.getBuilding() == castOther.getBuilding()) || (this.getBuilding() != null
                    && castOther.getBuilding() != null && this.getBuilding().equals(castOther.getBuilding())))
            && ((this.getStructure() == castOther.getStructure()) || (this.getStructure() != null
                    && castOther.getStructure() != null && this.getStructure().equals(castOther.getStructure())))
            && ((this.getApartment() == castOther.getApartment()) || (this.getApartment() != null
                    && castOther.getApartment() != null && this.getApartment().equals(castOther.getApartment())))
            && ((this.getNote() == castOther.getNote()) || (this.getNote() != null && castOther.getNote() != null && this
                    .getNote().equals(castOther.getNote())));
}

public int hashCode()
{
    int result = 17;

    result = 37 * result + (getCodeOkato() == null ? 0 : this.getCodeOkato().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result + (getCodeKladr() == null ? 0 : this.getCodeKladr().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result + (getPostalCode() == null ? 0 : this.getPostalCode().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result + (getRegion() == null ? 0 : this.getRegion().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result + (getHouse() == null ? 0 : this.getHouse().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result + (getBuilding() == null ? 0 : this.getBuilding().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result + (getStructure() == null ? 0 : this.getStructure().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result + (getApartment() == null ? 0 : this.getApartment().hashCode());
    result = 37 * result + (getNote() == null ? 0 : this.getNote().hashCode());
    return result;
}

}
```

Address.hbm.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated 16.08.2012 12:47:01 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="gen.Address" table="address">
    <composite-id name="id" class="gen.AddressId">
        <key-property name="codeOkato" type="string">
            <column name="code_okato" length="11" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="codeKladr" type="string">
            <column name="code_kladr" length="20" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="postalCode" type="string">
            <column name="postal_code" length="6" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="region" type="string">
            <column name="region" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="house" type="string">
            <column name="house" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="building" type="string">
            <column name="building" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="structure" type="string">
            <column name="structure" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="apartment" type="string">
            <column name="apartment" />
        </key-property>
        <key-property name="note" type="string">
            <column name="note" length="1500" />
        </key-property>
    </composite-id>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

How you can see in mapping file uses class Address.java. But with this class i cant set or get any parametrs like `apartment` or `building`. There only in AddressId class.
I all examples with hibernate what i see uses only one java class. What function of second class which hibernate fenerate.
So i wanna do all correct. And how i gonna generate java classes or use what i generete to waork with xml files and data base?

And another question how to create annotations in cenerated java classes autometiclly?

Comment: I do not prefer to generate classes from tables since Hibernate/JPA is all about entities which are objects and has relationships in them so its of more object relation mapping than database table mapping. And once you write them by hand its easy next time :)

Comment: i have 39 tables. Hand writing is bad solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate annotations instead of hbm.xml, you should uncheck *Hibernate XML mappings(.hbm.xml)* and choose *Generate EJB3 annotations*.

Hibernate generates separate class for ID when table's primary key consists of multiple columns. It also does so when table does not have primary key at all.

Comment: Can you give me advice. I want to create java classes to work with hibernate + jabx. I want to read xml files and write data to DB. What is most rational mehtod to create java classes for this?

Comment: Please post a new question, rather than add to comments here, when you're no longer discussing the original question.